# Is the damage of a hit dependant on the type of attack?

Tags: chivalry-medieval-warfare

In *Chivalry: Medieval Warfare*, there are 3 different types of attack - a swipe, a stab and an overhead.

I already know that different weapons do different amounts of damage, have different reach and different speed - but do the types of attack? So, for example, will a stab ever do more damage than a swipe with the same weapon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer : **yes**.

Each attack of each weapon does different damage.

Each class has specific resistance to the type of attack, and there is also a modifier for the body part, see the [wiki](http://chivalry.wikia.com/wiki/Damage) for numbers.

Comment: Wikia gives no answer to the question, doesn't mention the three types of attacks (swipe, stab, overhead) in the question common to all melee weapons.

Comment: What? Of course it does, I don't understand.